# Jquery search is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

On  keyup of an input I'm trying to do a live search from my database. But whenever I type somemthing I get an error saying

> Uncaught TypeError: value.voedselID.search is not a function.

How can I fix this? Here is how my json looks like

```js
[{
    "voedselID": 1,
    "voedselNaam": "Apple",
    "gram": 100,
    "carb": 11,
    "eiwitten": 1,
    "vet": 0,
    "calorieen": 49
  },
  {
    "voedselID": 2,
    "voedselNaam": "Kip",
    "gram": 100,
    "carb": 0,
    "eiwitten": 12,
    "vet": 3,
    "calorieen": 76
  }
]
```

And here is how my code looks like

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.inputUpdateFood', function(e) {
  var searchField = $('#inputUpdateFood').val();
  var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
  var output = '';
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/Voedsel/getAll', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      if (value['voedselID'].search(expression) != -1 || value.voedselNaam.search(expression) != -1) {
        output += '<input type="radio" name="foodSug" value="' + val.voedselNaam + '">' + val.voedselNaam + '<br>'

        $('.suggestion').append(output);
      }
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: Why do you expect that to be a function?  Where do you define that function?

Comment: WHY not use the regex and simply match?

Comment: I found the source code on 2 articles i thought it was a standard function but how do you "match" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search function seems to be a method of the String class.

So, you should convert the value to String.

Have you tried to use one of the following code in your condition ?

- `String(value['voedselID']).search(expression) != -1`
- `value['voedselID'].toString().search(expression) != -1`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_search.asp

Comment: You can also use `(value['voedselID'] + "").search...`

Answer (score 1):

- It is more understandable to use a regex match or test() but since your ID is numeric it needs to be a string to be used with a regex
- Your each is a loop on an array, not a key/value object

So

- searchField.match(re) or
- re.test(searchField) or
- searchField.search(re) !=-1

```js
var data = [{
    "voedselID": 1,
    "voedselNaam": "Apple",
    "gram": 100,
    "carb": 11,
    "eiwitten": 1,
    "vet": 0,
    "calorieen": 49
  },
  {
    "voedselID": 2,
    "voedselNaam": "Kip",
    "gram": 100,
    "carb": 0,
    "eiwitten": 12,
    "vet": 3,
    "calorieen": 76
  }
]
var searchField = "kip";
var re = new RegExp(searchField,"i"), output="";
$.each(data, function(_,item) {
  console.log(item,item.voedselNaam.match(re))
  if (String(item.voedselID).match(re) || item.voedselNaam.match(re) ) {
    output += '<input type="radio" name="foodSug" value="' + item.voedselNaam + '">' + item.voedselNaam + '<br>'
    $('.suggestion').append(output);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="suggestion"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is a better way to do it. I had only answer how to fix his code.